# How does this function work without setting the parameter?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading through Eloquent Javascript and saw this function:

```
function multiplier(factor) {
  return function(number) {
    return number * factor;
  };
}

var twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));
// → 10
```

However, I'm failing to grasp how the inner function is assigning the variable (5) to the number parameter? Eloquent JS tries to explain it but I'm not getting it.

Comment: After executing this line `var twice = multiplier(2);`, Twice is a function.  'twice = function(number) {
         return number * 2;
    };' And when you execute this line `console.log(twice(5));`
Number will have the value 5 and it will return 10

Comment: @Gilsha - Put that in an answer and you'll get my vote

Comment: So if twice becomes the inner function, what happens to the factor variable? Is it stored in memory or something? This could be obvious, but not to me...

Comment: Thanks @myfunkyside  This question is marked as duplicate. I cant answer it.

Comment: Note that a javascript variable can hold a function. Factor variable will hold the parameter value passed to the multiplier function. Here it is 2. Thats how twice become a function which returns number * 2

Comment: The duplicate is at the top, below the header. Although that is a very long post about closures, and while this may be a closure, I'm asking about a specific function.

Answer (score 1):

The inner function is the **return value** of `multiplier`. It doesn't get called until `console.log(twice(5));` where it is explicitly passed the value `5`.

Comment: And in the function, which is `5`? `number` or `factor`?

Comment: number of course: `return function(number) {`

Comment: Yeah.. "of course" is kind of useless in this situation don't you think? If we got how 'simple' this works, we wouldn't be asking..